# A simple lisp program

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to write this program to find a keyword in a list. If found then print the list. But errors occur, i can't solve it. Please give me some suggestions. I am a newbie for lisp.

The main program is two dolist(two for in C) and find keyword in a list of list(two dimension array).

```
(defun kanna_find (key)
  (let (
        (result 0)
        (kanna-table (list 
                (list "あ" "ア" "a")
                (list "い"　"イ"　"i")
               )
        )                               ;; End of kanna table
    )                                   ;; End of let var define
    (dolist (result kanna-table) 
      (dolist (item result)
      (if (string= item key)
          (print result))
        )                               ;; End of the second dolist
      )                                 ;; End of the first dolist
    )                                   ;; End of let
)

(kanna_find "あ")
```

Below is the debug info

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable 　)
  (list "い" 　 "イ" 　 "i")
  (list (list "あ" "ア" "a") (list "い" 　 "イ" 　 "i"))
  (let ((result 0) (kanna-table ...)) (dolist (result kanna-table) (dolist ... ...)))
  kanna_find("あ")
  eval((kanna_find "あ"))
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  recursive-edit()
```

Comment: Those are *kana* not *kanji*. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(list "あ" "ア" "a")
(list "い"　"イ"　"i")
```

Do you notice how the spaces in the second line are longer than the ones on the first line? That's because they're not ASCII spaces, so emacs doesn't recognize them as spaces. Rather emacs thinks they're variable names, so it complains to you that there's no variable called "　" (thus the space in the void-variable error).

Comment: It is the culprit. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be looking for this one-liner:

```
;; return a sublist tail of list-of-strings whose first element is string
;; or nil if string is not found
(member string list-of-strings)
```

Your code is terribly formatted. Try this style, which is used by about 99.5 million of the world's 100 million or so Lisp programmers:

```
(defun kanji_find (key)
  (let ((result 0)
        (kanji-table (list (list "あ" "ア" "a")
                           (list "い"　"イ"　"i"))))
    (dolist (result kanji-table) 
      (dolist (item result)
        (if (string= item key)
          (print result))))))
```

Nobody writes comments about individual closing parentheses; that is ridiculous! You're turning Lisp into Ada.

Your text editor (being Emacs, after all) can show you the balancing pairs of parentheses and manage the indentation for you.

In the end, the indentation is your main visual clue about what goes with what.

The `(result 0)` binding in your code is useless and has nothing to do with the `result` variable in the outer `dolist`.